# Best way to present and document long screens

Tags: design, users, user-centered-design, documentation, presentation

Currently I am using tools like Word, Powerpoint and Keynote to present concepts and specs to stakeholders.

What is the best – or optimal – way to present and document long screens for stakeholders?

This is especially a problem with long mobile screens. For example how do you present the bottom menus and other sticky elements? I personally hate to see designs where the bottom menu is at bottom of a long screen. It doesn't represent the reality.

Please share how do you do it and let's try to set a standard for this. :)

Comment: Define document!

Comment: Can you please explain how a "prototype doesn't fully replace good documentation"? They are two separate things. Documentation is good for style guides and recording work processes. Prototypes are good for demonstrating and visualizing concepts. I don't understand your argument here.

Comment: What do you mean by "_I personally hate to see designs where the bottom menu is at bottom of a long screen. It doesn't represent the reality_"? If you mean the content is longer than the height of the screen, and you need to scroll to see it all, and the menus etc. are at the bottom of all of that, then showing the menu at the bottom of all that _is_ reality, isn't it?

Comment: Ideally, you don't depend on documentation like that because, as you point out, it's unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a long screen then I like to introduce expand/collapse features - show the necessary information and then give the user the option to learn more about it via expand/collapse. This helps shorten the page and makes it easier to digest the important information.

Do you have examples of long screens to share?

Comment: I'm sorry I was being unclear. I meant how to document longs screens to present for stakeholders ex. for managers (concepts) and for developers (specs).

Comment: got it! but how are you presenting these documentations then? paper? computer files?

Comment: Made with ex. Word, PowerPoint, Keynote etc... I usually use Keynote to present concepts and for specs.

Comment: if you're using those programs, you'll want to chop up the screen into relevant sections right? also, you can try to think of your designs too in terms of components so engineers will know what you envision when you provide specs. for sticky elements you could present a few screens side-by-side to illustrate the concept. i personally would use a working prototype of some sort to do this though - it's easier to show how something is intended to work. where as specs, you can then work your program of choice and then provide it alongside the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

A tool like [Protopie](https://www.protopie.io/) allows you to keep sticky elements in your prototypes. I'm sure it integrates with Sketch also. This will solve your misery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but prototype doesn't fully replace good documentation. For example special scenarios are hard to cover in clickable prototypes. Usually prototypes focus on the "dream" flow where everything goes smoothly.

Comment: @imakesoft Can you define "good documentation"? Are we talking a Word document or...? Prototypes are the best way to visualize your concept in all states without actually building the damn thing.

Comment: Made with ex. Word, PowerPoint, Keynote etc... I usually use Keynote to present concepts and specs.

Comment: @imakesoft Okay thanks for the extra detail. In that case, I absolutely disagree with your statement "prototype doesn't fully replace good documentation". Even the most basic of prototypes completely replaces a 'good' old fashioned word document or keynote. Prototyping tools are DESIGNED to express and present concepts and specs. Word and Keynote are not. You should rethink your dated and limited strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Why not cut up all the different sections of the site, feed them piece by piece, and then, at the end, give them the whole site.